# how to get the shipping method name woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shopping-cart

how I get the woocommerce shipping method name after the customer apply the shipping method in the cart using the country, state and zip code?

I want to display the estimating delivery date by the shipping method that's why I want the shipping method name in the cart after customers apply the shipping method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write some jQuery to hook into the trigger event in cart.js

```
$( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
```

Use the code below and insert the jQuery you need to output the estimated delivery date where you'd like it positioned.  You'll need to check the name of your shipping method also I've just provided an example.

```
$( document.body ).on( 'update_checkout', function(){
    // check code is firing
    console.log('update_checkout function fired'); 
});
```

When you enqueue your custom script it needs the dependency of `wc-cart` and jQuery so make sure you add these to the `wp_enqueue_script` function.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Schultz. Thanks for the answer but it is worked when the more than one shipping methods available for the one zip code and you change it via the radio button. my requirements are the trigger also when there is one shipping method and it is applied after the customer add the zip code.

Comment: I don't really understand your reply.  The jQuery I have given you is the trigger point for when a shipping method is changed so all you need to do is fill in the appropriate code to do what you want.

Comment: It's the same trigger whether they change it or not.  When a user enters their details that trigger will fire.

Comment: Does it write a line to the console when you enter the shipping/billing details?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157564/discussion-between-mr-ajay-and-andrew-schultz).

Comment: I've modified my answer to use the update_checkout trigger which will fire on the page load of the checkout.